# Connect dcc.Store to Switch Input

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm trying to use Dash Mantine switch component and I'm trying to connect a dcc.Storage in session.
My solution works although I get a dependency loop error in console.

This is my dcc.Store initialized in main.py:
`dcc.Store(id="is_3d", data=False, storage_type="session")`

This is the code for the Switch:

```
dmc.Switch(
                    id="switch-3d",
                    size="lg",
                    radius="sm",
                    label="use the new algorithm",
                )
```

And those are the callbacks I use to connect the switch value with the store value:

```
@ callback(Output("switch-3d", "checked"), Input("is_3d", "data"))
def initSwitch(data, n_clicks, checked):
    return data if n_clicks == 1 else checked


@ callback(Output("is_3d", "data"), Input("switch-3d", "checked"))
def changeState(checked):
    return checked
```

The first callback meant to initialize the switch checked value from the existing store data that is stored in the session

The second callback meant to change the store value based on the switch checked value.

this is the error I get:
`{message: 'Circular Dependencies', html: 'Error: Dependency Cycle Found: is_3d.data -> switch-3d.checked -> is_3d.data'}`

I understand that there is a loop between the 2 callbacks. How should I fix this problem or is there any other way I should use to make both the switch and the store communicate with each other?

Comment: Callback examples are not very clear. Mentioned `initSwitch()` won't work: three parameters specified with only single input.

Answer (score 0):

With a prerequisite of minimal version `dash v1.19.0` such mutual dependencies can be handled within a single callback ([docs with examples](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks#circular-callbacks)). Specify all affected components as both inputs and outputs. Use context (`ctx`) to identify the source component. Use the value of the correspondent parameter for all outputs.

Example:

```py
from dash import ctx


@callback(
    Output('is_3d', 'data'),
    Output('switch-3d', 'checked'),
    Input('is_3d', 'data'),
    Input('switch-3d', 'checked'))
def changeState(session_data, layout_data):

    triggered_from_layout = (ctx.triggered_id == 'switch-3d')

    if triggered_from_layout:
        return layout_data, layout_data

    return session_data, session_data
```

Comment: wow, I think this answer is more efficient than the answer I gave. Thank You